# XML Serialization and Deserialization in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

```
<job id="ID00004" name="PeakValCalcO">
  <uses file="Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00003.grm" link="input" />
  <uses file="PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00003.bsa" link="output" />
</job>
<job id="ID00005" name="SeismogramSynthesis" >
  <uses file="FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s07930-h00000" link="input" />
  <uses file="Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00005.grm" link="output" />
</job>
```

Let say I have this XML I want to convert into .net Object how can do this i tried it but it doesn't work correct...

```
public class jobs : List<job> { }

    public class job
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<uses> Files { get; set; }
    }
    public class uses
    {
        public string file { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
    }



 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(jobs)); 
           TextReader tr = new StreamReader("CyberShake_100.xml"); 
           job b = (job)serializer.Deserialize(tr); 
           tr.Close(); 
    }
```

Comment: And what is not correct? Do you get an error or is the read object wrong - and if you get an error what error message do you get?

Comment: no error it does not run after  job b = (job)serializer.Deserialize(tr);

Comment: Do not forget to Dispose StreamReader :)

Comment: @Disposer fighting to honor his nick ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, there are several things wrong here:

**1) Your xml document has no root element**

It needs to look more like this:

```
<jobs>
  <job id="ID00004" name="PeakValCalcO">
    <uses file="Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00003.grm" link="input" />
    <uses file="PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00003.bsa" link="output" />
  </job>
  <job id="ID00005" name="SeismogramSynthesis" >
    <uses file="FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s07930-h00000" link="input" />
    <uses file="Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00005.grm" link="output" />
  </job>
</jobs>
```

**2) You need some xml serialisation attributes**

Attributes are used to [tell the .Net framework how to serialise and deserialise xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#Y1596).  Without these the .Net frameowork is just guessing at your xml format, and so won't do a very good job.  In this case you need:

- An `XmlRoot` attribute on your `jobs` class to tell the .Net framework what your root element type is
- Some `XmlAttribute` attributes to indicate which properties are serialised as attributes
- A `XmlElement` attribute to indicate that your array is serialised as a "flat" sequence of elements rather than as a nested array (and what those elements are called).

Combine all of this and your classes should look like this:

```
[XmlRoot("jobs")]
public class jobs : List<job> { }

public class job
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("uses")]
    public List<uses> Files { get; set; }
}

public class uses
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string file { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string link { get; set; }
}
```

For complex xml document this tends to get a bit tedious - there is a tool `XSD.exe` that will automate all of this for you.

**3) You are casting to the wrong type**

Even if the serialisation succeeds you will get an `InvalidCastExcpetion` trying to cast a `jobs` instance to `job`.  Try this instead:

```
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader("CyberShake_100.xml"))
{
    jobs b = (jobs)serializer.Deserialize(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that `id` and `name` on `<jobs>` are XML attributes - you need to express that in your classes, too:

```
public class job
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<uses> Files { get; set; }
}
```

The same applies to your `<uses>` tag and its class representation.

Also: a valid XML document always has **one root element** and one root only - your XML fragment is not a valid XML document.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XSD.exe tool to generate a class structure that matches your XML. It is probably the easiest way to have a working serialization object hierarchy.

Comment: You're right, but **XSD** tool adds a lot of stuff to your code! Maybe there are some tips I don't know, but when I used it it created a `.cs` file of about **800 lines** using a **7 lines** *XML* file.

Answer (score 1):

At least you need the `[XmlAttribute]` on id, name, file and link members.

You also cast to the wrong type, should be `jobs b = (jobs)serializer.Deserialize(tr);`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid XML document, since it has more than a single root. That's the reason you can't use something out-of-the-box from the framework.